# R - How to conditionally set multiple values in a vector based on a single current value

Tags: r

I have a data set similar to the example below. What I want to be able to do is assign all missing values the correct 'Title' value, based on the non-missing values and their associated 'Name'. So all entries with Name 'A' would have Title 'X', and similar for B and 'Y'.

```
Name | Title
-------------
A    |  X
A    |  NA
A    |  NA
B    |  NA
B    |  Y
B    |  Y
```

There should only be a single 'Title' value for each 'Name', although this one value may appear multiple times.

I imagine there are several tortuous conditional loops that could achieve this, but I'm curious if there are any tidier/more efficient ways to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be more elegant solutions, but this is pretty straightforward and should be fairly robust:

```
lu <- unique(df[complete.cases(df),])         ## Make a look-up table
df$Title <- lu$Title[match(df$Name, lu$Name)] ## Use it to find Name-->Title mappings

## Check that it worked
df
#   Name Title
# 1    A     X
# 2    A     X
# 3    A     X
# 4    B     Y
# 5    B     Y
# 6    B     Y
```

Comment: The last line could alternately be the following left join: `merge(df, lu, all.x = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3):

You can sort by name and title then use `na.locf` from the zoo package:

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(mydf[order(mydf$Name, mydf$Title),])

  Name Title
1    A     X
2    A     X
3    A     X
5    B     Y
6    B     Y
4    B     Y
```

Comment: Note that if it were possible that all the titles for a name were NA then the above would need to be extended like this:  `nalocf <- function(x) na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE); transform(mydf[order(mydf$Name, mydf$Title),], 
  Title = ave(Title, Name, FUN = nalocf))`   The other solution using dplyr would also need to be extended.

Answer (score 2):

You can also re-create that column based on the unique `Title` value, which is also non-NA, for each group.

Here's a `dplyr` version:

```
dt = data.frame(Name = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
                Title = c("X",NA,NA,NA,"Y","Y"),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)

dt %>% group_by(Name) %>%
  do(data.frame(Name = .$Name,
                Title2 = unique(.$Title[!is.na(.$Title)]),
                stringsAsFactors=F)) %>%
  ungroup

#     Name Title2
#    (chr)  (chr)
# 1     A      X
# 2     A      X
# 3     A      X
# 4     B      Y
# 5     B      Y
# 6     B      Y
```

And here's a `data.table` version:

```
dt = data.frame(Name = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
                Title = c("X",NA,NA,NA,"Y","Y"),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

library(data.table)

dt = setDT(dt)

dt[, Title2 := unique(Title[!is.na(Title)]), by="Name"][,Title:=NULL]
dt

#    Name Title2
# 1:    A      X
# 2:    A      X
# 3:    A      X
# 4:    B      Y
# 5:    B      Y
# 6:    B      Y
```

Not sure if you'd like to use an additional package for this task, but keep it in mind in case you ever need to create a very big look up table and you prefer to use a process like this.